# Sudo command in bash

Tags: bash, sudo

I am using bash script to retrieve files for an Arduino. I am using bash script instead of sudo. Here are my instructions:

The following command will clone the brewpi-script repository into /home/brewpi, an empty directory you should have created in the previous step. The python script will run as the brewpi user, so it is best if we run Git as the brewpi user too, so all new files are owned by the brewpi user. We do this by adding sudo -u brewpi to the command.

```
sudo -u brewpi git clone https://github.com/BrewPi/brewpi-script /home/brewpi
```

I have learned I don't need the sudo command, but the -u is giving me a "command not found" error. What is the bash equivalent to "-u"?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -u brewpi` is one command with one parameter (username). Skip this command with its parameter, so simply run:

```
git clone https://github.com/BrewPi/brewpi-script /home/brewpi
```